# How to keep focus in inputbox

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, servicenow

Just like in the datalist HTML tag, I need to be able to keep the focus in an input box even if the user clicks on a suggestion or navigates through the suggestions with key down.

I'm trying to make my own autocomplete field. Just like ng2-controler or mat-autocomplete in material, but I can't use these because I can't add libraries or modules on the server.

For now, I have a working input box showing a suggestion list under it when it has the focus. When the user press a key, the suggestions are re-evaluated. 
The problem is that when the user clicks on a suggestion (a tag with ng-onclick), the input box lost focus so the suggestions disappear, and the onclick is never triggered.

```js
 //filteredUsers is an array with this kind of values :

 filteredUsers = [ {"letter" : "A",
                    "names" : ["albert@mail.com", "alice@mail.com"],
                   {"letter" : "P",
                    "names" : ["philip@mail.com"]}
                 ]
```

```html
<div>
  <div>
    <input type="text" ng-focus="c.focus = !c.focus"
           ng-blur="c.focus = !c.focus" class="form-control"
           ng-model="c.email">
  </div>
  <div class="datalist panel-body"
       ng-if="c.focus && c.filteredUsers.length > 0" style="">
    <span class="select2-search" ng-repeat="obj in c.filteredUsers">
      {{obj.letter}}
        <ul>
          <p ng-repeat="email in obj.names">
            <a href ng-click="getMyCtrlScope().change(email)">{{email}}</a>
          </p>
       </ul>
    </span>
  </div>
</div>
```

I would like to the input box doesn't lose focus when the user selects a suggestion in the list. Of course, the focus must be lost when the user select another object than the input box or the suggestions.

Comment: just in the your change function do inputElem.focus() or just set a value of c.focus to true.  c.focus = !c.focus doesnt make sense

Comment: I don't know angularJS but I think you can trigger input focus event after selecting suggestion.

Comment: In any case, you could implement your own suggestion box, using an element (e.g: div) that appears/disappears when the user clicks on it

Comment: @JoeWarner I forgot to mention that point. c.focus is a boolean defined in the client script, by default it is false. This is what triggers the appearance of the div containing the suggestions.

Answer (score 1):

One approach is to save the element that has focus:

```
<input ng-model="x" save-focus="lastTarget=$target">
```

```
app.directive("saveFocus", function() {
  return { link: postLink, };
  function postLink(scope, elem, attrs) {
    elem.on("focus", function (e) {
      scope.$apply(function() {
        scope.$eval(attrs.saveFocus, {$target:e.target});
      });
    });
  }
})
```

Then have the element being clicked change the focus back:

```
<button ng-click="x=+x+1" re-focus="lastTarget">
```

```
app.directive("reFocus", function() {
  return { link: postLink, };
  function postLink(scope, elem, attrs) {
    elem.on("click", function(e) {
      scope.$eval(attrs.reFocus).focus();
    })
  }
})
```

### [The DEMO](https://plnkr.co/edit/VTbJRIuWG8fATKe8KVE1?p=preview)

```js
angular.module("app",[])
.directive("saveFocus", function() {
  return { link: postLink, };
  function postLink(scope, elem, attrs) {
    elem.on("focus", function (e) {
      scope.$apply(function() {
        scope.$eval(attrs.saveFocus, {$target:e.target});
      });
    });
  }
})
.directive("reFocus", function() {
  return { link: postLink, };
  function postLink(scope, elem, attrs) {
    elem.on("click", function(e) {
      scope.$eval(attrs.reFocus).focus();
    })
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="//unpkg.com/angular/angular.js"></script>
<body ng-app="app">
    <input ng-model="x" save-focus="lastTarget=$target">
    <br>
    <button ng-click="x=+x+1" re-focus="lastTarget">
      Increment X
    </button>
</body>
```